# Why is my Matlab_kernel not working in the Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter

Hello I have a problem with Matlab in Jupyter and couldn't solve it for hours... So I am asking you for help. 
I followed this tutorial (https://anneurai.net/2015/11/12/matlab-based-ipython-notebooks/#comment-89) step by step but still it does not work somehow.

I can start the jupyter notebook and even make a matlab notebook by clicking New -> Notebooks -> Matlab. My problem starts when i try to run a cell. Here is the console output when i open my matlab notebook:

```
Kernel started: a430b794-d98a-4f85-a9d8-639777b51f26
//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/nbformat.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.nbformat` package has been deprecated. You should import from nbformat instead.
  "You should import from nbformat instead.", ShimWarning)
/bin/sh: matlab: command not found
[W 13:11:01.814 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from a430b794-d98a-4f85-a9d8-639777b51f26
```

My .bash_profile contains the following lines:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:$PATH"
#
export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE=/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/matlab
# added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

What did i do wrong? 
I am thankful for every help!

UPDATE: 
I added

```
export PATH="/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin:$PATH"
```

to my .bash_profile file. Now it seems like the computer finds the matlab executable but now i have problems with the license.

```
[I 14:43:21.154 NotebookApp] Kernel started: c47cd696-35cf-44b4-93d0-ac130b5d18de
//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/nbformat.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.nbformat` package has been deprecated. You should import from nbformat instead.
  "You should import from nbformat instead.", ShimWarning)
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -9
Your username does not match the username in the license file. 
To run MATLAB on this computer, you must run the Activation client to reactivate your license.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2015a/9

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: MATLAB 
License path: /Users/myuser/.matlab/R2015a_licenses/license_358437_R2015a.lic:/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/licenses/license.dat:/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/licenses 
Licensing error: -9,57.
```

The thing is: I am using a student version for matlab and if I open the program (by double-clicking) it works perfectly and it says that I my license is activated. However, i suspect that if i try to open it with jupyter the username is different. Does someone have had the same problem/a solution? Or does someone know how to find out the username if using jupyter notebook?

Comment: have you tried putting the matlab executable into your PATH?

Comment: Yes, i also tried that. I added the line: 
export PATH="/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/matlab:$PATH"
to my .bash_profile, but still it does not work. 
I still get /bin/sh: matlab: command not found

Comment: it should be `export PATH="/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin:$PATH` after that, start a new shell and make sure that `which -a matlab` prints `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/matlab`. Then try to start jupyter again.

Comment: Yes that made a progress! thanks, now i got a different problem - a license problem. i updated my question.

Comment: @cel, could you explain why there is only one " in your export statement?

Comment: @TomNorway, simple typo, it should have been `export PATH="/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Great thanks :) The number of different syntax possibilities with export is confusing!